# How to plot Poisson distribution simulations in ggplot?

Tags: r, statistics

I need help plotting 10,000 simulations of a Poisson distribution of a random variable with lambda = 8 in a histogram in R with probability mass on the y-axis. I have been trying different ways to implement this but I'm always running into errors. I would appreciate any help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do;

```r
hist(rpois(10000, 8), freq = FALSE)
```

[image]